# Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection

Tags: java, xml, spring, xsd

I am using Spring and in `application-context.xml` I have the following definitions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd"
   >
```

.....

**When my internet connection is lost, I cannot run my application via tomcat or jetty.**

It gives:

```
[main] WARN  org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document '/spring-beans-2.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:96)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:380)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:2541)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDHandler.java:2532)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:1836)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:531)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2408)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1753)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:685)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:626)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3095)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:921)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java:115)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:383)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:210)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:483)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:678)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:553)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:523)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:371)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:181)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:356)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:356)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
2009-11-13 15:31:25,675 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 23 in XML document from class path resource [application-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinit........
```

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

There is no need to use the classpath: protocol in your schemaLocation URL if the namespace is configured correctly and the XSD file is on your classpath.

Spring doc "[Registering the handler and the schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration)" shows how it should be done.

In your case, the problem was probably that the spring-context jar on your classpath was not 2.1. That was why changing the protocol to classpath: and putting the specific 2.1 XSD in your classpath fixed the problem.

From what I've seen, there are 2 schemas defined for the main XSD contained in a spring-* jar. Once to resolve the schema URL with the version and once without it.

As an example see this part of the spring.schemas contents in spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

This means that (in xsi:schemaLocation)

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
```

will be validated against

```
org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd
```

in the classpath.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

or

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
```

will be validated against

```
org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
```

in the classpath.

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.1.xsd
```

is not defined so Spring will look for it using the literal URL defined in schemaLocation.

Comment: For those who need a summary: Spring can't find the schemas in the classpath. The Spring core JAR has a schema->filename mapping that is included in the JAR. If it cannot resolve this it'll go to the web.

Comment: I have declared it like this "http:////www.springframework.org/schema/context http:///www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd". I have the 4.0 jar in the Glassfish/domains/domain1/lib. Whenever i deploy the project, glassfish refers to internet. Is this issue specific to glassfish-4.0? (added more '/'s for formatting)

Comment: I think the new "Registering the handler and the schema" link should be here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration

Comment: @Dirk - that link appears to be broken

Comment: @Stormcloud, yes, the original link appears to be back and the one I suggested broken. Here's the latest document link: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xml-custom.html#extensible-xml-registration

Answer (score 27):

I solved it

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       classpath:spring-context-2.1.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-2.0.xsd"
       >
```

---

`classpath:spring-context-2.1.xsd` is the key for working offline mode (no internet connection). Also i copied `spring-context-2.1.xsd` near (same directory) the application-context.xml file

Comment: For intellij users who might run into this. This works even though intellij doesn't recognize the classpath syntax inside schemalLocation and highlights it as a error.

Comment: A huge thank you @DaveParoulek - the error was throwing me off but this absolutely does the trick.

Answer (score 19):

Something like this worked for me.

```
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
             classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
             classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-context-3.0.xsd"
```

Comment: Yes this works because the xsd is packaged inside the spring jar. So no need to check on springframework.com when you can use the xsd inside the jar :)

Comment: This solution worked for me because i had the spring dependences inside a jar i mean as a external jar and without internet fails your solution worked very well for me thanks a lot a god bless.

Comment: @godlikeNoob I tried this but its giving again error "cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'."

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone arrives here via the same root I did - I hit this problem because I was building a single JAR with all dependencies, including Spring JARs. As a result the *spring.schemas* file in some of the *META-INF* directories of Spring JARs was overwritten.

I found suggested solutions here: [How to create spring-based executable jar with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160534/how-to-create-spring-based-executable-jar-with-maven)

Answer (score 5):

Ran into a similar issue today.  In my case, it was the shade plugin that was the culprit, in addition to springframework.org having an outage.  The following snippet cleared things up:

```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
   <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
</transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
</transformer>
```

HTH someone

Comment: where the above snippet needs to add?

Answer (score 4):

You should check that the `spring.handlers` and `spring.schemas` files are on the classpath and have the right content.

This can be done with `ClassLoader.getResource(..)`. You can run the method with a **remote debugger** in the runtime environment. The extensible XML authoring setup is described in the [Spring Reference B.5. Registering the handler and the schema](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration).

Normally, the files should be in the spring jar (springframework.jar/META-INF/) and on the classpath when Spring can be initiated.

Comment: hi, your solution is very complex; i don't understand what do you mean ? 

http://www.jroller.com/marshbourdon/entry/using_spring_2_x_xml, i tried this but it doesn't work. Any suggestions ?

It couldn't be complex to work a webapp while there is no internet connection. am i right ? 

Thanks.

Comment: Spring should work out of the box. Something with your classpath is incorrect. My answer contained only some hints to analyze your problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Find class path

If you are using eclipse click on corresponding jar file. Goto ->META-INF-> open file spring.schemas

you will see the lines something like below.

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd

copy after =   and configure beans something like below.

`<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:rabbit="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit" 
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit classpath:org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context classpath:org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd">`

Comment: I made this change in the xml **http://www.springframework.org/schema/rabbit classpath:org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd** but it says Failed to read schema document 'classpath:org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/config/spring-rabbit-1.6.xsd' ? any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to add schema locations to your bean definition, and then they can be found in classpath instead of fetched over the net. Given your formatting problems, I'm not 100% sure that you aren't doing this already.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">
<!-- empty: the beans we use are in the base class's context. -->
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the JAR files that you use in your application.

What I did, which worked, was to get inside the JARs for SPRING-CORE, SPRING-BEANS, SPRING-CONTEXT, SPRING-TX that match the version I am using. Within the META-INF folder, I concatenated all the spring.handlers and spring.schemas that come in those JARs.

I killed two birds with one stone, I solved the problem of the schemas so this also works correctly in offline mode.

P.S. I tried the maven plugin for SHADE and the transformers but that did not work.

Comment: How did you solved this problem, can u please help me to understand that. I am in need.

Answer (score 1):

We solved the problem doing this:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
factory.setValidating(false); // This avoid to search schema online
factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaLanguage", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
factory.setAttribute("http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxp/properties/schemaSource", "TransactionMessage_v1.0.xsd");
```

Please note that our application is a Java standalone offline app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse for your development , it helps if you install STS plugin for Eclipse [ from the marketPlace for the specific version of eclipse .

Now When you try to create a new configuration file in a folder(normally resources) inside the project , the options would have a "Spring Folder" and you can choose a "Spring Bean Definition File " option 
 Spring > Spring Bean Configuation File .

With this option selected , when you follow steps , it asks you to select for namespaces and the specific versions :

And so the possibility of having a non-existent jar Or old version can be eliminated .

Would have posted images as well , but my reputation is pretty low.. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add some additional aspect of this discussion. In windows OS I have observed that when a jar file containing schema is stored in a directory whose path contains a space character, for instance like in the following example

```
"c:\Program Files\myApp\spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
```

then specifying schema location URL in the following way is not sufficient when you are developing some standalone application that should work also offline

```
<beans
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
    />
```

I have learned that result of such schema location URL resolution is a file which has a path like the following

```
"c:\Program%20Files\myApp\spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar"
```

When I started my application from some other directory which didn't contain space character on its path then schema location resolution worked fine. Maybe somebody faced similar problems? Nevertheless I discoverd that classpath protocol works fine in my case

```
<beans
 xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. For posterity, my exception was:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 117;
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd'
```

I solved it when I realised the the version of `spring-beans` specified in my Maven `pom.xml` was `4.1.x`, thus meaning the specific `.xsd` could not be found on the classpath.

This was masked for a long time because I normally am online, so I thought being offline had "broken" the build. But it really had nothing to do with it. Updating my `pom.xml` to specify the correct version of `spring-beans`, namely `4.2.x`, fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I'm using spring-context version 4.0.6 and 
spring-security version 4.1.0.

When changing spring-security version to 4.0.4 (because 4.0.6 of spring-security not available) in my pom and security xml-->schemaLocation, it gets compiled without internet.

So that mean you can also solve this by:

- changing spring-security to a older or same version than 
  spring-context.
- changing spring-context to a newer or same version than 
  spring-security.

(any way spring-context to be newer or same version to spring-security)

Answer (score 0):

I had ran into this similar problem as well. In my case, my resolution is quite different. Here's my spring context xml file:

```
...
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
...
```

I'm not specifying any xsd version as I want spring to use the latest xsd version inside spring dependencies. The spring version my application used was **spring-beans-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar:4.3.1.RELEASE** and when I assembly my application into jar, all spring dependencies exist in my classpath. However, I received following error during startup of my spring application context:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

After some hard time troubleshooting, I found the issue is due to the **index.list** inside the META-INF folder of my jar file. With **index.list** file, spring namespace handlers cannot be located to parse the spring application context xml correctly. You can read more about this spring issue [SPR-5705](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-5705)

By removing indexing from my **maven-jar-plugin**, I manage to resolve the issue. Hope this will save some times for people having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the relevant spring jar file are in your runtime classpath. In my case this we were missing spring-tx-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar from runtime classpath. After adding this jar, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no internet connection in your platform and you use Eclipse, follow these steps (it solves my problem)

1. Find the exact xsd files (You can unzip these files from their jars. For example, spring-beans-x.y.xsd in spring-beans-x.y.z.RELEASE.jar)
2. Add these xsd files to Eclipse XML Catalog. (Preferences->XML->XML Catalog, Add files)
3. Add these files location to configuration file. (Be careful, write the exact version of file)

Example:

> xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
>   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-x.y.xsd "

Answer (score -2):

Remove jars you added recently in the web-inf ->lib. for example jstl jars.