# Spring and Jax-WS : where are xsd schema?

Tags: web-services, spring, jax-ws

In spring file **applicationConfig.xml**, JAX-WS integration need some specific schemas.
I recently successfully use these declarations :

- https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
- https jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd

[I must remove all url (except one) because it's my first question]

The file begins with those declarations : 
`<beans xmlns="http www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
 xmlns:tx="http www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:ws="http jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core" xmlns:wss="http jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http www.springframework.org/schema/beans http www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http www.springframework.org/schema/aop http www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http www.springframework.org/schema/tx http www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http www.springframework.org/schema/context http www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core https jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet https jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">`
`(...)`
`<ws:service id="myService" bean="#myWS" />`
`<wss:binding url="/services/myws" service="#myService" />`

Now, a migration occurs for website jax-ws.dev.java.net. These files are not found and I have some errors under Tomcat and Eclipse :

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Is there a solution or something to prevent this error ?

Thanks

Comment: Hey I am facing the same problem. Did you get any solution of it ?

Answer (score 4):

Finaly I extract XSD from **jaxws-spring-1.8.jar** (lib for jax-ws to work with Spring).
I put these XSD under WEB-INF directory, just near **applicationContext.xml**.
I modify declaration of schema in this file with :

```
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core classpath:spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
   http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet classpath:spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd
```

I have seen the solution here :
[Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're using maven for building? Try adding the dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1-1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you're not using maven, make sure you have jax-ws libs on your classpath.
http://java.net/projects/jax-ws

Comment: It's not a compilation problem... I put all libs in my classpath. Errors occur when application is deployed under Tomcat. I think that spring read applicationContext.xml and try to read all XSD schema.

Comment: Having it compiling and adding a jar to the classpath are two different things. that said, what did help me in this situation was adding a maven dependency of `<groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring</groupId>`, `<artifactId>jaxws-spring</artifactId>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extract the XSD from the jaxws-spring jar. 
You just need to make sure the URL you use corresponds to that in the META-INF/spring.schemas file in the jar

They are defined as follows:

```
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd=spring-jax-ws-core.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd=spring-jax-ws-servlet.xsd
http\://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/local-transport.xsd=spring-jax-ws-local-transport.xsd
```

Think you just need to replace https with http. E.g:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
          http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core.xsd
          http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd>
```

For more info on spring.schemas, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/extensible-xml.html#extensible-xml-registration-spring-schemas)