# Spring Configuration Error: (cvc-etl.1)

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I tried everything I can think of, but nothing seems to work.

I am using the current version of `Spring Framework (3.2)` in my java web application.
Every time I start my project I get the following error:

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

this is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"

</beans>
```

I tried to :

1. change the version of the schema (3.2, 2.0...)
2. copy the schema from the jar into WEB-INF
3. change unix EOL into windows EOL

and nothing seems to work, except using the DTD declaretion instead of the XSD.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring is having trouble finding the xsds.  Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182857/getting-error-message-with-spring-cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-ele).  If you are sure you have the required spring-beans jar in your classpath, you may have a corrupted META-INF/spring.schemas file.  The spring.schemas file tells spring which classpath to use to find the corresponding xsd file in the spring jars.  I have had this occur when using the maven-shade plugin improperly configured.

Answer (score 0):

The xsd came down fine for me when I pasted it in the browser.

This one works fine for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="example"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: my computer is not connected to the internet, so i can't run this test