# Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, message-queue

I have the spring jars of `spring-3.2.0.RC1.jar` and trying to implement `Apache ActiveMQ` `helloWorld` program from tutorial given [here](http://icodingclub.blogspot.com/2011/07/introduction-of-spring-jms-with.html). The xml configuration file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">

    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" id="destination">
        <constructor-arg value="TEST.Q1"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" id="connectionFactory"
        p:brokerurl="tcp://localhost:8161"></bean>

    <bean class="com.jms.helloworld.listner.MessageListenerImpl" id="simpleMessageListener">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer"
            id="jmsContainer">
            <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>
            <property name="destination" ref="destination"></property>
            <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListener"></property>
        </bean>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        System.out.println("LISTNER STARTED");
        ApplicationContext context =  new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("src/com/jms/helloworld/config/JMSConfig.xml");
    }

**Exception on console**


LISTNER STARTED
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 10 in XML document from file [/home/neal/workspace/ActiveMQListener/src/com/jms/helloworld/config/JMSConfig.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.jms.helloworld.test.TestJMSListner.main(TestJMSListner.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 10; columnNumber: 61; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:387)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:321)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1920)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:709)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3080)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:899)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 14 more
```

I don't know what is wrong with the beans.So far any suggestion in other question doesn't help. Any help?

Comment: the xml validator is complaining that <beans> is not a valid element. This validates in an external xml site. can you open http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd from where you are? does copying it local help? could be a firewall issue.

Comment: Could be this reason [getting-error-message-with-spring-cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-ele][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182857/getting-error-message-with-spring-cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-ele?rq=1

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try this, assuming you're on Spring 3.1:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
```

Replace `3.1` on the last line with whatever *major* Spring version you use. Meaning: there is no `3.1.1` XSD even though there is a Spring version `3.1.1`.

Comment: Just to be explicit: you have to match your spring library version with the XSD version.

Comment: See the options in org.springframework.beans.factory.xml of spring-beans package.

Answer (score 7):

Found it on another thread that solved my problem... was using an internet connection less network.

In that case copy the xsd files from the url and place it next to the beans.xml file and change the xsi:schemaLocation as under:

```
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
spring-beans-3.1.xsd">
```

Comment: No need to copy. The xsd is already in the jar. Something like this should work:

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      classpath:org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

Answer (score 5):

Add this code     ..It helped me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
         xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
           classpath:/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
         classpath:/org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        classpath:/org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
         ">      
     </beans>
```

Comment: In some internal corp environment, accessing external network to get schema is not always feasible. In this case, the solution here works perfectly.

Comment: Solved our problem in an offline environment. It's a bit tricky that IDEA would mark the classpath in red as an unresolved reference while it actually works fine.

Answer (score 1):

This error of Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans' but for a whole different reason

It turs out my internet connection was not very reliable, so i decided to check first for this url

http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd

Once I saw that the xsd was open succesfully I clean the Eclipse(IDE) project and the error was gone

If you try this steps and still get the error then
check the Spring version so that it matches as mentioned by another answer

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-**[MAYOR.MINOR]**.xsd">
```

Replace [MAYOR.MINOR] on the last line with whatever major.minor  Spring version that you are using

For Spring 4.0
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd

For Sprint 3.1
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
spring-beans-3.1.xsd

All the contexts are available here
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the root cause turned out to be white-space (shown as dots below) after the www.springframework.org/schema/beans reference in xsi:schemaLocation, i.e.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans....
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this same as you.
With my solution as follows:

1. Reconfig file: Spring Configuration File (no use XSD namespace declaration).
   [image: 2.]
   -> with the main purpose of not having tag name( bean, ...)
2. Create tag  with class you want to use.
   [image]
   ---HappyCoding---

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this using the following code.

```
<? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8 ?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 

</Beans>
```

Comment: This worked for me but not sure why because I am using spring 5.2.8 can anyone tell me why it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this- Spring 4.0. Working

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans                                               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if all the spring jar file's version in your build path and the version mentioned in the xml file are same.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was my file encoding...I used powershell to write the xml file and this was not UTF-8 ...
It seems that spring requires UTF8 because as soon as I changed the encoding (using notepad++) it works again without any errors

Now i Use in my powershellscript the following line to output the xml file in UTF-8:
[IO.File]::WriteAllLines($fname_dataloader_xml_config_file, $dataloader_configfile)

instead of using the redirection operator > to create my file

Note: I didn't put any xml parameters in my beans tag and it works

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that spring was not able to download http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd or http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd

However I was able to access those from my browser as it was using my machines proxy. So I just copied the content of the two xsds to files named spring-beans.xsd and spring-context.xsd and replaced the http url with the file names and it worked for me.

Comment: Another thing I tried that worked was , I reverted my changes kept my namespace as before without any local xsd. And rather ran my jar with proxy args as : java -Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxyHost -Dhttp.proxyPort=myproxyport -jar xyz.jar   And it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spring 5.1.0.RELEASE, the configuration file format specified in [an answer for another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52659844/4698969) works for me.

This is the copy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
     
    <!-- Bean declaration and other configurations -->
     
</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is the spring version related issues. Just try to change spring version to lower or 4.1.8.RELEASE

Answer (score -4):

Use this to solve your problem:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Comment: this is in no way related to the question.