# Do we have XSDs particularly for Spring 5.x?

Tags: java, spring

Can anyone please let me know if the Spring 5 version of XSDs are available?

Is there something like `spring-beans-5.1.xsd`, `spring-context-5.1.xsd`, `spring-mvc-5.1.xsd` or `spring-beans-5.0.xsd`, `spring-context-5.0.xsd`, `spring-mvc-5.0.xsd` available in Spring ?

If available, please provide the links for those XSDs.

Also, can anyone let me tell what is the compatible version of `spring-security` for `Spring 5.x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is no XSD available for Spring 5.**

---

**Note:** *Instead of providing the explicit version of XML schema better go for the generic XML schema which can support any version of spring.*

---

## XSD version support list :

### For spring-mvc :

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd **(Generic)**

### For spring-context :

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-2.5.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-3.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-3.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-3.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-4.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-4.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-4.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context-4.3.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-context.xsd **(Generic)**

### For spring-beans:

- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
- http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-beans.xsd **(Generic)**

---

*So, I would recommend you to go for generic XSDs because this reduces the confusion to pick which XSD version for Spring version that you are using.*

Just an example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
     
    <!-- Bean declaration and other configurations -->
     
</beans>
```

---

Let's say if you are using spring-core `5.0.4.RELEASE`, then compatible version of spring-security is `5.0.2.RELEASE`.

If maven project, then add these dependencies in pom.xml :

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.4.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

### How to check which version of spring security is supported by spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context & so on ?

1. Open https://mvnrepository.com
2. Type spring security in the search box
3. Press enter.
4. Click on spring security core.

[image]

5. Click on the version that you want to use. Let's say I have opened 5.0.2.RELEASE, then see for compile dependencies. It will show the list of library that it supports.

[image]

6. See for the version of spring-beans, spring-context & so on.

### Or

If it's a normal project, then download jar from https://mvnrepository.com and add the appropriate spring jars needed in your project.

### Or

You can download Spring version jar zip (all in one) from here: https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/spring/

Extract it and add all the jars to your project on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks Anish. 
But we have the below links for spring 3.0, spring 4.2 xsd's http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 


My XML files has the bean definitio as below.

Comment: Thanks Anish. 
But we have the below links for spring 3.0, spring 4.2 xsd's http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd 

I could not find similar links for spring 5 xsd's
My XML files has the bean definition as below.

`xsi:schemaLocation=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd"`

Need to replace this 4.2 with 5.0

Comment: Can we get similar links for spring 5 xsd's

Comment: I found upto 4.3 XSD. xsi:schemaLocation=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd There is no spring xsd for 5.0.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please guys have a look.

Comment: Should it be `http` or `https`?

Comment: @wonsuc It will be http