# What is attribute namespace in html + javascript for? (setAttributeNS)

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Many of us non-jquery javaScript developers, have been using [domElement.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute), and its sister functions, to hack our way around countless dom elements, for all of internet eternity.

Be it, css, dom classNames, storing/retrieval of variable data, etc...

```
var b = document.getElementById("someDiv"); 
b.setAttribute("align", "center");
```

---

So what's the purpose / practical use of its [domElement.setAttributeNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttributeNS) variant? This question is in regards to web browser display / uses. And not in the context of XML. In which setAttributeNS has lots of uses.

```
var d = document.getElementById("someDiv"); 
d.setAttributeNS("http://www.mozilla.org/ns/specialspace", "align", "center");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML Documents (i.e. Document objects create by the `text/html` parser) there really aren't many uses for `setAttributeNS`.

But if look at what the HTML5 parser is required to do when parsing foreign content (i.e. SVG abd MathML) we find [this table: adjust foreign attributes](http://w3c.github.io/html/syntax.html#adjust-foreign-attributes).

So it automatically moves and renames some attributes into the XLink, XML and XMLNS namespaces. When you are manipulating the DOM via functions like setAttribute and setAttributeNS, that automatic moving and renaming won't happen, so to get the attributes into their correct namespaces, you need to use setAttributeNS to create and modify them.

`xlink:href` is possibly the most common of these to be set via setAttributeNS()

Answer (score 2):

That's `domElement` not `htmlElement`.

It is useful when you are working with a DOM constructed from XML that uses elements from multiple namespaces.

(And if you want to know why namespaces are useful, then [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863233/how-do-xml-namespaces-work))

Comment: in the context of XML. That I would understand, however the example on MDN clearly uses NS, in the context of display manipulation. (2nd example). Of which i fail to grasp

Comment: They're using an XML format that describes presentation for the example. There are lots of different XML formats that do that.

Comment: Hmm, I guess... "Its meant for XML (domElement). And not htmlElement (which inherits domElement)" & "the example on MDN is just an example"... would count as an answer +_+ , . Haha