# Spring bean configuration xml

Tags: spring, configuration-files

In Spring config xml we have  tag and in that tag we have xmlns, xsi etc..
what all these details means ? When and how these details matters?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">   
</beans>
```

thanks,

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863233/how-do-xml-namespaces-work

Comment: did you find the solution by on given link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the nice answer of xsi:schema use here [Use of xsi:schemaLocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875021/what-is-the-use-of-xsischemalocation)

And this spring document will help you understand the spring configuration in details [XML Schema-based configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-config.html)