# How does XML Namespaces work?

Tags: php, xml, namespaces

I'm wondering how does XML namespaces work. I read they should be unique etc. But none of resources stated how they exactly work.

What I mean i have XML node like

```
<name xml:lang="en" type="abc">A name</name>
```

And to extract `xml:lang` with php (SimpleXML) i need to use following code:

```
$obj->attributes('http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace');
```

How does this link define/tell SimpleXML to extract `xml:*` attributes? I Only see web page there, not single definition that would define this namespace.

As [How do XML namespaces work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863233/how-do-xml-namespaces-work) states URLs are never resolved. But document i parse does not contain this link (namespace definition).

Also, in question above, there are defined namespaces. Where they define that this namespace is exactly `human:*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"How does this link define/tell SimpleXML to extract `xml:*` attributes? I Only see web page there, not single definition that would define this namespace."*

`xml:` is a special prefix that predefined in the XML specification. It is the prefix to which namespace name `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace` is bound, and this is how that 'link' connected to the prefix `xml`. See : [W3C : The "xml:" Namespace](http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace).

> *"Also, in question above, there are defined namespaces. Where they define that this namespace is exactly `human:*` ?"*

The prefix `human` is not declared anywhere in that XML. I believe that was by mistake though, as the XML is not well-formed in its current form. The prefix declaration should've been `xmlns:human` instead of `xmlns:html` at the `human:body` element :

```
<human:body xmlns:human="http://www.example.com/human/">
    <human:height>182 cm</human:height>
    <human:weight>83 kg</human:weight>
</human:body>
```

Comment: So basically `xmlns:human="http://www.example.com/human/"` defines XML Namespace `human` identified (identifier used for extraction/accss) by `http://www.example.com/human/` identifier?

Comment: @Gacek yup, that part defines the mapping of prefix `human` to the namespace name/uri `http://www.example.com/human/`