# Disable schema validation with Spring

Tags: java, xml, spring, xerces

During my unit tests, I want to avoid the connection to Internet used by Xerces to validate the XML application context files (for Spring). How can I do it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: I didn't include the good version of the JAR of Spring with the schema included. Finally, using the good version of the schema in my application context file, i don't have the error anymore.