# Fail to deploy JSF into Weblogic 12.1.1(failed to load java type corresponding to e=web-app@http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee)

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic12c

I try to deploy the hello1 jsf tutorial example on Weblogic 12.1.1, but it fail with errors. Is something need to be changed on the web.xml?

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Maybe you have no internet connection ( or firewall block) on server, where you are trying to deploy application. Check if you have access to "http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd".
See solutions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)

Comment: In my case, it failed due to the last extra "/" in xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebLogic 12.1.1 is a Java EE 6 application server ([Fusion Middleware What's New in Oracle WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm)).

The Java EE 6 specification specifies that it support Java Servlet Specification Version 3.0.

You are attempting to use a Servlet 3.1 deployment descriptor in your web.xml file.

Your application should deploy if you change the opening `web-app` element to:

```
 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
```

Comment: Seem like replacing every single xmlns.jcp.org to java.sun.com is required.

Comment: That's why I provided the entire header for you.

Comment: In my case, it failed due to the last extra "/" in xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/"