# schema not works when no internet connection

Tags: spring-mvc, xmlschemaset, spring-config

schema works fine during internet connection but it shows me following warning message when internet connection is off

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML Schema) referenced in the document.

i have used following schemas in spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">
```

what should i do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using the schema which is a public URL. It is obvious trying to download from the internet.
 If you use relative path for the downloaded schema, it should work (but it is not recommended)

EDIT:
After going through some posts, I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection).Hope it helps