# How to dissable xsd validation on start up server (Spring)

Tags: spring, xsd-validation

How can I avoid XSD validation of the application.xml file for Spring when starting up the server?

My company has the access cut to go out to the internet in some servers and the application fails on start up because it can't validate against the XSD in http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd for example.

Comment: Spring doesn't need internet as it ships internally with the XSD. If it fails that basically means you have something wrong/weird in your setup.

Comment: Only fails in an enviroment where there is no out to the internet, in all other it works..

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection ?

Comment: It shouldn't need internet... Heck been working offline for ages without problems. Hence it must be something in your setup. Spring is shipping with the xsd internally especially to circumvent the need for a live connection.

Answer (score 1):

All you are right too. If version in XSD is the same as the version of the libraries it don't go to internet..

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd

instead of

http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd

It works too!

Answer (score 0):

Implementing my own

```
public class CustomXmlWebApplicationContext extends XmlWebApplicationContext {

        protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader beanDefinitionReader) {
            super.initBeanDefinitionReader(beanDefinitionReader);
            beanDefinitionReader.setValidating(false);
            beanDefinitionReader.setNamespaceAware(true);
        }

    }
```

and in web.xml

```
 <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>net.axisdata.cache.web.CustomXmlWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

It works!

Comment: As stated you shouldn't need this.