# Spring MVC deplyment error with weblogic server

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, weblogic, offline

I need to deplay Spring MVC apllication with web logic. But the mainconcern is the server doesn't have internet access. This is servelt-context.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.boi.controller" />

</beans:beans>
```

When deply the war file in the weblogic it generate this error

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "appServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "boireceipt.war". org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 9 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 115; <Line 9, Column 115>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd' at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149) at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124) at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422) at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282) at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1984) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1958) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1877) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3173) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1529) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:488) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:573) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:327) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 115; <Line 9, Column 115>: XML-24500: (Error) Can not build schema 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans' located at 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd' at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrorHandler(XMLError.java:425) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLError.flushErrors1(XMLError.java:287) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:422) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:239) at oracle.xml.jaxp.JXDocumentBuilder.parse(JXDocumentBuilder.java:155) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75) at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ... 58 more Caused by: oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException: Duplicated definition for: 'identifiedType' at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.buildSchema(XSDBuilder.java:795) at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDBuilder.build(XSDBuilder.java:490) at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDValidator.processSchemaLocation(XSDValidator.java:999) at oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDValidator.startElement(XSDValidator.java:604) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseElement(NonValidatingParser.java:1598) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseRootElement(NonValidatingParser.java:455) at oracle.xml.parser.v2.NonValidatingParser.parseDocument(NonValidatingParser.java:401) ... 62 more :oracle.xml.parser.schema.XSDException:Duplicated definition for: 'identifiedType'
```

Please what could be the issue with this deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be duplicate of [Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)
Problem seems to be that the schema validation needs an internet connection to resolve the xsd. If that is not possible you will need to point to xsd on your classpath